# Error with inlining a namespace function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I want to make sure that one of my function is inlined when using it, but for some reason I'm getting errors which I can't understand. I quickly setup a test environment to reproduce my error. Here it is:

Main.cpp:

```
#include "ns1.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    if (Test::GiveMeCookies(false)){
        std::cout << "Here it is!\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "You were a bad boy!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

ns1.cpp:

```
#include "ns1.h"

__forceinline bool Test::GiveMeCookies(bool why)
{
    return !why;
}
```

ns1.h:

```
#pragma once

namespace Test
{
    __forceinline bool GiveMeCookies(bool why);
}
```

The error message I'm getting is:

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl Test::GiveMeCookies(bool)" (?GiveMeCookies@Test@@YA_N_N@Z) referenced in function _main
>
> 1>C:\Users\Unknown User\Desktop\NamespaceTest\Debug\NamespaceTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Could anyone explain me why I can't inline functions from my namespace? How can I workaround this while keeping that I **HAVE TO** force inline it.

Comment: Why do you think you need to "force" inlining?

Comment: To give the compiler a fighting chance of inlining the function, the definition needs to be visible at the point where the function is called.   Otherwise, it cannot inline, and leaves it to the linker to find a (non-inlined) version at link time.  Which probably means (yuck!)  that your main.cpp needs to include ns1.cpp.

Comment: You do realize that unless you enable LinkTimeOptimisation, if the function is actually in a `.cpp` file, it WON'T be inlined, whether you ask for it to be force or otherwise.

Comment: Actually if I write my whole code into a single header, then it works (just tried right now). It doesn't seem to be the best option yet, but better than nothing :)

Thank you for your advise Mats!

 Lightness Races in Orbit: It would be quite hard to understand, it has a littlebit deeper reasons, in ASM, but I don't want to question it if it's really needed :) I've got my reasons [ might be stupid or not, I just don't want to start an argue about it :) ]

Answer (score 2):

The error you get is not related to forceinline.
In ns1.cpp your function is not in the the Test namespace.

it should be like this:

```
#include "ns1.h"
namespace Test
{
  __forceinline bool GiveMeCookies(bool why)
  {
      return !why;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why should I take that Test:: out? That indicates that I want to define a function from the Test namespace, according to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cb46ksf.aspx

Comment: Niclas, nor that works, except If I expand everything in my header. (Just found out recently)

Comment: original.roland, are you certain that you are compiling ns1.cpp and not only Main.cpp ?

Comment: Yes, as I'm using Visual Studio, and it's output is: http://pastebin.com/NN0bAtCC I think your solution  should work if I #include "ns1.cpp" instead of the header.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an extern to the header seems to solve the situation, however I have to dig into it deeper to check if it really inlines. If not, then I think we can't do any further steps, so probably it's the best solution:

```
#pragma once

namespace Test
{
    extern __forceinline bool GiveMeCookies(bool why);
}
```